# How to get Assembly by its Assembly Name/ Default Namespace in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm aware that we have `Assembly.GetAssembly(Type type)` which lets you get the assembly by a type reference in the application. But is there a standard way to get an Assembly by its Assembly Name or Default Namespace?

For example: If I have a project named "Awesome.Namespace.WebApp" I would expect to get the assembly using something like this: `Assembly.GetAssembly("Awesome.Namespace.WebApp")`.

This is something I always come across when I don't want to get the assembly using a Type (or when I can't rely on that project having that respective Type)

Comment: `var assembly = Assembly.Load(name);` ?

Comment: Its also possible to loop over all existing ones to find yours by name. Not the best solution but sometimes okayisch AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()

Comment: @BenjaminSchröder the main problem with that is that it assumes that it has already been loaded into the app-domain

Comment: @MarcGravell yeah that's true but Assembly.GetAssembly also just returns already loaded assemblys or am I completely wrong?

Comment: @BenjaminSchröder which is why I suggested `Load` :) If you're using the `Assembly.GetAssembly(Type)` API, then: it *must* already be loaded, for you to have a `Type` instance

Answer (score 1):

There is a way by using `Assembly.Load` method which has many different [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=netframework-4.7.2), one of them accepts string which should be "The long form of the assembly name."

Comment: Examples I've seen with `Assembly.Load` always use the "full qualified name" of the Assembly which contains a lot of noise. Does it work with the Default Namespace though?

Comment: @ThiagoM "default namespace" isn't a concept that exists in a compiled assembly; that just tells the IDE what namespace to use when you add a new source file (and some other things for web-projects, that evaporate once it has been compiled)

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok, sure. But still, the problem with `Assembly.Load` is that it expects me to pass something like this (which is awful): 

"SampleAssembly, Version=1.0.2004.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8744b20f8da049e3"

PS.: I can't believe that's the only way of doing this